# Creating a linked list from a file in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I have the function

```
Bell* reading(FILE* fp, int* numbptr)
{


Bell* newPtr;
newPtr = malloc(sizeof(Bell));
if (newPtr == NULL){
   printf("Error");
}

while( newPtr!= NULL){


fread(newPtr->brand, sizeof(Bell), sizeof(newPtr->brand), fp);
fread(&newPtr->price, sizeof(Bell), sizeof(newPtr->price), fp);
}
```

which seems to create the first node, but I'm not sure how to link this first node to the next. I realize I haven't even created the second node yet. Linked Lists are completely new to me.

Also, with the above code I'm getting a stackdump error. Not sure why this is.

The struct is as follows:

```
typedef struct bell
{
    char brand[20];
    int price;
    struct Bell* nextBell;
} Bell;
```

Answer (score 0):

In this context, you'll normally set the `next` element to 0 (NULL) in this function.  This completely initializes one element (though you should be checking that the `fread()` calls succeed, and your error message should end with a newline, and be printed to standard error — `stderr` is intended to be used for reporting errors, after all).

Your `while` loop is inappropriate.  Or, if it is appropriate, you have to do the memory allocation inside the loop; otherwise, each new entry will simply overwrite the last, leading to chaos.  You also need to add each element to the list inside the loop, and know what points to the head of the list.  A global variable is a common answer in beginner code; it is not a good answer (but it works because the code doesn't have to adapt to handle multiple lists at the same time, etc).

Your function doesn't use the `numptr` argument either.  Best to leave out unused parameters until you find you have a need for them.  (Of course, if you're coding to an interface, you may need it immediately even though you don't use it.)

Your calling code is then responsible for linking the single `Bell` structure into the list.  Often that is done with:

```
Bell *head = 0;

Bell *node;
while ((node = reading(fp)) != 0)
{
    node->next = head;
    head = node;
}
```

This repeatedly reads a single record (I'm assuming an appropriately revised interface and function body) and adds it to the front of the list (by far the easiest way to add it to the list).

I would probably rename the function `read_bell` or thereabouts.  And if you want to encapsulate reading many bells into one function, then I'd still have a function to read one bell entry, and another function containing the loop that repeatedly calls the 'read one bell entry' function.

If you have different requirements, you should say so up front.  Incomplete specs lead to incorrect programs.